# Entity Framework power tools pre generating view - error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using entity framework power tools 4 (beta). My project uses asp.net identity and EF 6.1.2. I have updated all the entity framework dlls via nuget. When I attempt to pre generate a view with EF Powertools for my dbcontext i receive the error :

Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I have updated my EF to 6.1.2 so it is the latest.
Has anyone else experienced this issue and solved it. I've seen people on the EF Powertools site posting similar issues to this but there's no solution I can find.

Thanks

UPDATE : - I have reinstalled all the packages with no luck. I have even gone as far as giving the solution to someone else to install on their pc - and they can run it and generate the views using power tools without the error. So it's probably something to do with my environment. Any ideas what to try changing ?

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexAttribute` is a new feature that is added in [Entity Framework 6.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index). 
You say that you have updated to 6.1, but the error suggests that you have a reference to version 6.0.

Can you remove **all** references to EF and `System.Data.Entity` and then try to install it again with Nuget?

Comment: Hi. I have done this with no luck. If I look at the entity framework dll reference in the object browser I can see the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.IndexAttribute there so I know the correct dll is being referenced. I still get the error when using EF Power tools and trying to pre generate the views. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Power tools use the IDE version of EntityFramework and not the referenced. Please check my solution [EntityFramwork Power Tools error while generating views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809880)